# Why is the ordered square $[0,1]^{2}$ first countable in the dictionary order?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

¿Why is the ordered square $[0,1]^{2}$ first countable in the dictionary order? I suppose for any point in $[0,1]^{2}$ I must find a countable basis, but I do not know yet what it should be or how to argue it.

Comment: Use the rationals.  The only issue will come at the square's borders.

Comment: Any separable ordered space is first countable.